# TypeScript export usage

Tags: typescript, module, export

I wrote some TypeScript codes that I want to use it as a package, but I could not prepare my export and import syntax. Is anyone can help me to reach my approach ? You can see my definitions on picture below

[image]

How can I combine my functions in a one namespace or class to reach my expected import statement.  You can fork and edit my code.
Thanks for advice.

My actual implementation

```js
import {
  utilAFunction1,
  utilAFunction2,
  utilBFunction1,
  utilBFunction2
} from './src/utils';

utilAFunction1();
utilAFunction2();

utilBFunction1();
utilBFunction2();
```

My expected implementation

```js
import { utils } from './src/utils';

utils.utilAFunction1();
utils.utilAFunction2();

utils.utilBFunction1();
utils.utilBFunction2();
```

Also my project file structure is

```
src
 utils
  util-a
   index.ts
  util-b
   index.ts
  index.ts
index.ts
```

```js
// util-a > index.ts
export function utilAFunction1(): void {
  console.log('Util A function 1');
}

export function utilAFunction2(): void {
  console.log('Util A function 2');
}
```

```js
// util-b > index.ts
export function utilBFunction1(): void {
  console.log('Util B function 1');
}

export function utilBFunction2(): void {
  console.log('Util B function 2');
}
```

```js
// utils > index.ts
import { utilAFunction1, utilAFunction2 } from './util-a';
import { utilBFunction1, utilBFunction2 } from './util-b';

export { utilAFunction1, utilAFunction2, utilBFunction1, utilBFunction2 };
```

```js
// src > index.ts
import {
  utilAFunction1,
  utilAFunction2,
  utilBFunction1,
  utilBFunction2
} from './src/utils';

utilAFunction1();
utilAFunction2();

utilBFunction1();
utilBFunction2();

/*
// my expected import statement and usage
import { utils } from './src/utils';

utils.utilAFunction1();
utils.utilAFunction2();

utils.utilBFunction1();
utils.utilBFunction2();

*/
```

[StackBlitz page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-export-example?devtoolsheight=33&embed=1&file=index.ts)

Comment: I added more code example, at question time I forgot to add them, thanks for warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My expected implementation
>
> ```
> import { utils } from './src/utils';
>
> utils.utilAFunction1();
> utils.utilAFunction2();
>
> utils.utilBFunction1();
> utils.utilBFunction2();
> ```

If it doesn't have to be **exactly** `import { utils } from...`, you can do this without any changes to `utils`:

```
import * as utils from './src/utils';
```

That imports the *module namespace object* for the module, which has read-only properties for all named exports in the module, and (if the module has a default export) a `default` property for the default export.

Alternatively, if you really wanted it to be specifically this:

```
import { utils } from './src/utils';
```

...then you could add this to `utils`:

```
export const utils = { utilAFunction1, utilAFunction2, utilBFunction1, utilBFunction2 };
```

But beware that the properties on that aren't read-only like they are on the module namespace object, though you could easily make them read-only:

```
export const utils = Object.freeze({ utilAFunction1, utilAFunction2, utilBFunction1, utilBFunction2 });
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I go into modules -- including the various `import` and `export` options available -- in Chapter 13 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: ````export const utils = Object.freeze({ utilAFunction1, utilAFunction2, utilBFunction1, utilBFunction2 });
```` usage helped to me